# Passing variables to a Custom Zend Form Element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm trying to create a custom form element which extends Zend_Form_Element_Text with a validator (so I don't have to keep setting up the validator when I use certain elements). Anyway, I'm having trouble passing $maxChars variable to it when I instantiate it in my Main form. I've provided my shortened code below

**This is my custom element below**

```
class My_Form_Custom_Element extends Zend_Form_Element_Text
{

public $maxChars

public function init()
{
    $this->addValidator('StringLength', true, array(0, $this->maxChars))
}

public function setProperties($maxChars)
{
    $this->maxChars= $maxChars;
}
}
```

**This is where I instantiate my custom form element.**

```
class My_Form_Abc extends Zend_Form
{
public function __construct($options = null)
{
    parent::__construct($options);
    $this->setName('abc');

    $customElement = new My_Form_Custom_Element('myCustomElement');
    $customElement->setProperties(100); //**<----This is where i set the $maxChars**

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit ->  setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

    $this->addElements(array($customElement ,$submit));
}
}
```

When I try to pass '100' using $customElement->setProperties(100) in my Form, it doesnt get passed properly to my StringLength validator. I assume it's because the validator is getting called in Init? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`init()` is called when you create an element, so before you call `setProperties()` and your `$maxChars` is not set then.

I see two solutions:

1 - Remove `init()` and move `addValidator()` to `setProperties()` method:

```
public function setProperties($name, $value)
{
    switch( $name ) {
        case 'maxChars':
            $this->addValidator('StringLength', true, array(0, $value));
            break;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

2 - Do what you did in `init()` in `render()` - element is rendered at the end.

```
public function render()
{
    $this->addValidator('StringLength', true, array(0, $this->maxChars))
    return parent::render();
}
```

I think first is better one.

Comment: Thanks mate, I don't know why I didn't think of the first solution. The second solution is something new to me though, They both work well. cheers =)